# Angular change host "localhost" to "projectName"

Tags: angular

When running my angular project, I want to change the localhost url to projectname.

localhost:4200 to projectName:4200

How should I proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change localhost/site to site.dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090759/how-to-change-localhost-site-to-site-dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved,
I added 127.0.0.1 projectName in the file "C: \ Windows \ System32 \ drivers \ etc \ hosts". Later, when I typed "ipconfig / flushdns" at the command line, I made "ng serve --host projectName" again and my project worked on projectName: 4200.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the serve with `ng serve`, just add `host`:

`ng serve --host="projectName"`.

Here are all parameters accepted by `serve`: [Angular ng serve Docs](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

**IMPORTANT**
This implies that you cannot serve the app if you don't have any address with that name